# using requirejs to only load jquery plugins on user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am starting to play with require js / modular development for the first time and am liking what I see.

What I am trying to achieve is basically only load certain custom jQ modules when needed. My main goal is page performance. At present I am only loading require.js (which in turns loads jQ async) then other jQ code/plugins only fire on user interaction.

Would the following code be considered good/bad practice? Is there anything anyone would change? (super basic example below)

MAIN.JS

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery"], function($) {

    // overlay plugin
    $("a").on("click", function(e){
        var self = this;
        require(["overlay"], function (overlay) {
            overlay.init(self);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

OVERLAY.JS

```
define(function () {
  return {
    init: function(self) {
        $.ajax({
           url: self.href,
           success: function (data) {
              $("#results").html($(data).filter('#details').html());
           },
           dataType: 'html'
        });
        $('#results').fadeIn();
    }
  }
});
```

Cheers,
Adi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of loading `overlay` is a correct use of require, however a couple of things:

Overlay.js should list jQuery as a dependency. Ensure your modules have all the code they need to run. In this case it's fine (as you're grabbing jQuery in the `require`) but say you used `document.addEventListener` to attach your click then you're no longer sure jQuery will be available for use by the `$.ajax`. It's nice to know your modules ask for everything they need rather than getting it by luck.

One rule I try to follow is to keep all my DOM related stuff in `main`. So for example:

**Overlay**

```
// Example code, and not complete
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');

    return {
        init: function(elements) {
            this.trigger = $(elements.trigger);
            this.target = $(elements.target);

            this.trigger.on('click', this.someEvent.bind(this));
        },

        someEvent: function() {
            this.getAjax();
        }
    }
});
```

And then in `main.js` just pass in the DOM elements

```
require(['overlay'], function(overlay) {
    overlay.init({
        trigger: 'a',
        target: '#results'
    })
});
```

Keeping the DOM elements separate and in one place makes updating them breeze. You could also pass in an options object for other things (such as class names) much like a jQuery plugin does.

Finally, in your example code your `$('#results').fadeIn();` is outside the success callback and would run immediately.